# How to prevent automatic update in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch

In my Spring boot batch application, I am calling a JPA repository class from Tasklet.
The JPA call retrieves a particular value (Entity object) from DB. The problem is, If I update some value in the entity object, once the control goes out of Tasklet, it automatically updates to DB even though I am not calling any save operation. How to prevent this? Default JPA implementation is Hibernate.

*Tasklet class*

```
Employee employee = employeeRepository.fetchEmployee(employeeName);
List<Address> addressList = employee.getAddress();
addressList.forEach(e -> e.setStatus(Status.INVALID.toString()));
```

*Repository*

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query("select em from Employee em where em.employeeName = :employeeName")
    public Employee fetchEmployee(@Param("employeeName") Long employeeName);
}
```

*Entity class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3769636546619492649L;
    private Long id;
    private List<Address> address;
    private String employeeName;
    
    // Getters and setters
    // @OneToMany mapping to Address
}
```

Even though I am not calling a .save() operation, it automatically updates Address table Status to "INVALID"

Comment: If you don't want the change, why do you update the value in the first place?

Comment: Please share the code of your tasklet and the configuration of the transaction manager you use for that tasklet. The tasklet will be executed in a transaction driven by Spring Batch (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#taskletStep), and in the case of JPA, any changes to the objects attached to the persistence context could be flushed to the database if the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Deep cloning to solve your issue.

First override the clone method inside your Address class like below.
Note : Please customize the implementation of `clone()` method by adding your  class attributes.Since you didn't mention the structure of the class Address , I have implemented the solution with my own defined class attributes.

**Address class**

```
public class Address {

    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String district;
    private String addressValue;

    public Address() {
        super();

    }

    public Address(String country, String city, String district, String addressValue) {
        super();
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.district = district;
        this.addressValue = addressValue;
    }
 //Getters and Setters 

   @Override
    protected Object clone()  {
        try {
            return (Address) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            return new Address(this.getCountry(), this.getCity(), this.getDistrict(),this.getAddressValue());
        }
    }

}
```

Then re construct your class Tasket like below.

**Tasket Class**

```
Employee employee = employeeRepository.fetchEmployee(employeeName);
List<Address> addressList = employee.getAddress();
List<Address> clonedAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
addressList.forEach(address -> clonedAddressList.add((Address)address.clone()) );
clonedAddressList.forEach(address -> address.setStatus(Status.INVALID.toString()));
```

Answer (score 3):

This happen because the entity is not in detached state. In EJB we can do this in the following way.

**EJB solution**

```
@Query(value = "select * from Employee WHERE EmployeeName = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public List<Employee> fetchEmployee(String employeeName);
```

This will make the transaction closed. Changes you make to entity will not get saved in DB

**Spring JPA**

After a bit of research i found JPA doesn't provide the detach functionality out of the box.

Refer : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/641

To make it work we can have a custom JPA repository which overrides detach method. An example is given in this link.

https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/1428895.html

Comment: @TransactionAttribute seems to an EJB annotation. How it fits here